# How do I save an output file to the folder it belongs to in c using MacOs

Tags: c, file, directory

The file currently saves to /Users/benreaby while  I want it to save to the source folder of the executable

```
// Filename that I want to save to the source 
// folder that the executable is located in
#define FILENAME "TACmFile.txt" 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "hello world");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using MacOS

Comment: If you build from the command line, and run from the command line, you wouldn't be asking this question. So I'll assume you're building and running from within an IDE. In that case, you need to set the working directory in the project configuration. The details depend on the IDE that you use.

Answer (score 3):

When an executable is run, and a relative file path is used, the file TACmFile.txt will be written in whatever the current working directory is when the executable is run. This does not necessarily bear any resemblance to the directory where the source code is located.

You need to specify an *absolute* path if you want to override this. You may need to have your executable read from a configuration file to get the filepath information.

Comment: Presumably rather than the source code directory the executable's location might be the desired reference – if so it might be discovered from `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution.  It depends on the presence of the executable path and file name in argv[0].  Your code is modified here to add new function  merge_pf(), which uses the executable's path found in argv[0].  It strips the executable name from the path and appends the desired file name to that same path.  This new string can be used to open the file of your choice, in the program directory.

This code is tested by me as win32.  Path tokens ('/') are added for Unix -- hence, should work there too -- *but not tested*.  **Please test/check to see if your OS supports the key principle of argv[0] containing program path and filename before using this code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* merge_pf() expects path to have exe name, ie: 'F:/dir/program.exe'.
   Param fname is some filename, ie: 'file.txt'
   Example final string would be: 'F:/dir/file.txt'
*/
char *merge_pf(const char *path, const char *fname)
{
    int  iii;
    char *path_file = malloc(strlen(path)+strlen(fname)+1);

    if(path_file)
    {
        strcpy(path_file, path);
        iii=(int)strlen(path_file);
        while(iii--)
        {
            if(path_file[iii]=='\\' || path_file[iii]=='/') /* DOS or Unix path token*/
                break;  /* Stop if we hit the last token */
            path_file[iii]='\0';    /*strip .exe name from path*/
        }
        strcpy(&path_file[iii+1], fname); /* merge path and file name*/
    }
    return path_file;
}

// Filename that I want to save to the source 
// folder that the executable is located in
#define FILENAME "TACmFile.txt" 

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
    char *pf = merge_pf(argv[0], FILENAME);
    FILE *fp;

    if(pf)
    {
        printf("Will open: %s\n", pf);
        fp = fopen(pf, "w");
        if(fp)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "hello world");
            fclose(fp);
        }
        free(pf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A test to see if your OS has Program Path and File name in arv[0] might look something like this...(there may exist an even safer way):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
    const char *pf = argv[0];

    if(pf)
    {
        printf("Program Path and File name: %s\n", pf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Success will look something like:

```
    Program Path and File name: f:/PROJECTS/32bit/_HELP/C/H118/math.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In every POSIX system, when a program is loaded by the kernel, it is loaded in memory from a file that is specified as the first parameter of any of the exec*(2) system calls.  The different variations of the system call normally implement different APIs and ways to locate the executable.

The most general format for the exec system call requires you to pass it the program name (a name of a file that exists on the filesystem) the `argv` array of strings representing the parameters to the program (including it's name) and the `envp` array of strings representing the environment of the progrm.  As these three things can be arbitrarily specified by a program, there's no fixed and predictable way for a program to know where in the filesystem the program was found, except if that information is passed along to the program by the process that executed the `exec(2)` system call.

For example, if you call

```
    execle("bin/program", "a", "b", "c", NULL, envp);
```

you will ask the kernel to find the program on the `"bin"` directory under the current working directory, but as the 0th parameter is `"a"` the program will receive an argument list composed of the strings "a" (program name), "b" (first parameter) and "c" (second parameter), wo the normal way of determining how the program was called has not been followed and `argv[0]` will not tell us anything useful about the file that was loaded in memory.  As the environment is also specified, even if we had some idea or access to the `argv[0]` parameter, the environment is different, and in case of a call like:

```
    execle("program", "program", "a", "b", NULL, envp);
```

the program will not be able to find the location of the program by using the `PATH` environment variable, as the `PATH` environment variable used to search for the program is different than the one passed through the exec() call.

if you are lucky, the shell will tell you something (if you run a *good shell*)  because it will pass you automatically the exported environment, and also the program name used to call the program, so you can follow the same algorithm that the shell used to find your program, to find an executable file that can be the program used by `exec()`, but there's still the race condition that the program file is renamed and not accessable from that path.

All of this said, you can check if the directory is present in the `argv[0]` and use that (but cutting from the last '/' char) and use that as the directory.

In linux, there's the possibility of checking "/proc/self/cmd" to get the file name used to call exec, but if the path name is relative (with no '/' chars present), and the `PATH` variable has been changed for the `exec()` you will not be able to follow the same list of directories that were in use to find the executable.

Normally, this doesn't fail, and the common procedure consists in checking the `argv[0]` string and try to extract the executable file name from that path, and use it as the directory name of the directory to write the file to.  This is not completely reliable, but works in the majority of cases.